# Getting specific word from doc file respective of uppercase/lowercase using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to get some word in .doc file and append them all in list.

Doc file content : 
`"i love Audi 
i love audi
i love AuDi "`

When I give audi or Audi as an input, it should read all these three different "audi" and return list containing all three different audi.

Comment: Are you able to read the doc file? It is best practice to post what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try regular expression where you do findall on word and ignore case

```
import re

doc_content = 'i love Audi i love audi i love AuDi and audis  but not audits or audiences'

results = re.findall(r'\baudi[s]?\b', doc_content, re.IGNORECASE) #The ? metacharacter will match only one 's' following audi to include the plural form and the \b at the end will exclude other words that begin with audi.

print(results)
['Audi', 'audi', 'AuDi', 'audis']
```

Here is the link for regex in Python - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to use Regular Expressions.

```
import re
string = "i love Audi i love audi i love AuDi"
result = re.findall('[A,a][U,u][D,d][I,i]', string)

print(result)
['Audi', 'audi', 'AuDi']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

doc_content = 'i love Audi i love audi i love AuDi... but not audis'

results = re.findall(r'\baudi\b', doc_content, re.IGNORECASE) #use \b at start and end to match whole word. This will exclude audis.

print(results)
['Audi', 'audi', 'AuDi']
```

This works for me. I was looking for this only. \b has solved my issue. Thanks :)